# How to get fancybox gallery to run on ajax loaded content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, gallery, mouseenter

I am loading some content via ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
          url: loadscript
        }).done(function(data) {    
            var main_content = $("#main_content", data);
            $(ajaxbox).html(main_content);
        });
```

To make fancybox work on this ajax-loaded content, i use

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.fancybox', function(){

    $(this).attr('rel','gal').fancybox({

        ...................

    }); 
});
```

instead of

```
$('.fancybox').attr('rel','gal').fancybox({

        ...................

});
```

But with this method, the fancybox gallery-function does not work.

The rel-attributes are set correctly, i also tried to define them in directly in the html output code instead of attracting them, which made no difference.

So, how to make the gallery-function work with the mouseenter method **or** get fancybox to run on ajax-content without the mouseenter-method?

Comment: Did you try $('.fancybox').attr('rel','gal').fancybox({... right after             $(ajaxbox).html(main_content); ??

Comment: Do you want to display the ajax-loaded content in fancybox ?? ... or : do you want to bind the ajax-loaded content to fire some other content in fancybox? please clarify